# WPF Masked TextBox using dependency attached Property

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, datepicker

Can you suggest me how to  do masking for DatePicker(datepickerTextBox) or TextBox? That mask format should be a date pattern(depends on locale). That behavior have the events to complete the incomplete date and converts 2 digit year to 4 digit year.

```
    public static void uiControl_PreviewTextInput(object sender,TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

        MaskControl txt = (MaskControl)sender;
        e.Handled = true;

        int position = txt.SelectionStart;

        int seperatorPosition = maskProvider.ToDisplayString().IndexOf('/');

        if (position < txt.Text.Length)
        {
            position = GetNextCharacterPosition(position);
            if ((Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert) && maskProvider.Replace(e.Text, position)) ||
                     maskProvider.InsertAt(e.Text, position))
            {
                position++;
            }
            //position = GetNextCharacterPosition(position);
            txt.Text = maskProvider.ToString();

            if (position == seperatorPosition)
            {
                position = seperatorPosition++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code and what do expect as a result exactly? Minimum but complete program demo would be nice.

Comment: Sorry I don't have perfect code.I have code which is availed in the stackoverflow only.. My mind is blocked... please someone help me to write code..

Comment: The problem is cursor is not moving to the next field